# Is a parent keeping me from transparency

Tags: java, javafx

I have an animation that switches screens (it's from Angelas famous youtube vid).

```
Timeline fade = new Timeline(
  new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)),
  new KeyFrame(new Duration(500), (ActionEvent t) -> {
    getChildren().remove(0);
    getChildren().add(0, schermen.get(naam));
    Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
      new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
      new KeyFrame(new Duration(600), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
    fadeIn.play();
}, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)));
fade.play();
```

Now with this 1 screen fades out, they get switched and the new one fades in. Now when 2 screen have the same size this is no problem everything looks smooth. But when your new screen isn't the same size this doesn't look good.

I was thinking to find a sweet transition for this. So I thought let's fade out the old screen. Remove the old screen. Set new screen to invisible, maximize it and only then fade it in. This way the user doesn't notice the transition that much.

So I fade the old screen out to invisible:

```
            if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            Timeline switchscreenmaximize = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)),
                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(500), (ActionEvent t) -> {
                        getChildren().remove(0);
                    }, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)));
            switchscreenmaximize.play();
```

And this is where it goes wrong. The screen just goes blank instead of transparent. Did I miss something? Or is it a parent that I'm seeing that is blank?

Comment: Is the `Stage` you are trying to make transparent set to `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`?

Comment: Did you try it with transparent?

Comment: Yes. You got me on the right track though. I wasn't setting the stage transparent but a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Stage transparent not a child.